# Change country with blue card

Tags: germany, netherlands, blue-card

I have a blue card and I'm living in Germany for the past 6 months. I received a job offer to move to the Netherlands. Do I have to apply for a new blue card in the Netherlands?

Comment: Yes, since residence permits are country specific.

Answer (score 1):

Almost first Google search gives me next https://ind.nl/en/work/working_in_the_Netherlands/Pages/EU-blue-card-holder.aspx